# Exchange of variables between node js and powershell

Tags: node.js, powershell

I have a powershell script which runs node js. I want to return variable from node js to power shell and based on the value returned power shell script should follow the next steps.

I have tried using system environment variables but that is not sustaining once after returning from node js to power shell

Comment: You can use `console.log` to print something back to the terminal and than use this something as a value

Comment: Thanks @Konrad ! I am newbie to powershell can you please brief on the suggestion you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

`test.ps1`:

```
$var = node test.js
Write-Output $var
```

`test.js`:

```
console.log('10')
```

Running:

```
./test.ps1
```

Outputs:

```
10
```

Comment: $var = node test.js, this is not running test.js. It got struck

Comment: What happens instead?